# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in common.inc on line 2287 when registering new user

Tags: 7, users

I am receiving this error message when registering as a new user on a site-in-progress:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in common.inc on line 2287

The actual line 2287 is:

> $query += $options['query'];

Here is the surrounding code:

```
// Without Clean URLs.
  else {
    $path = $prefix . $path;
    $query = array();
if (!empty($path)) {
  $query['q'] = $path;
}
if ($options['query']) {
  // We do not use array_merge() here to prevent overriding $path via query
  // parameters.
  $query += $options['query'];
}
$query = $query ? ('?' . drupal_http_build_query($query)) : '';
$script = isset($options['script']) ? $options['script'] : '';
return $base . $script . $query . $options['fragment'];
  }
}
```

I use LoginToboggan, not sure if that has anything to do with this issue. Does anyone have any ideas on what might cause this issue and how it can be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: What exact version of drupal are you using 7.? - In drupal 7.22 that line number is not the same line as you mention.

Comment: I'm going to guess that it is line 2214 in drupal 7.22

Comment: If you're not sure if a module (in this case, Logintoboggan) has anything to do with a problem, first disable the module, then clear the Drupal cache, and then try to reproduce the problem again.  Debugging in this way yourself first will help other people help you much faster.

Comment: @rooby, I am using 7.22.  Patrick Kenny I just disabled LoginToboggan, and that did "fix" the issue. So it looks like the issue is with LoginToboggan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the url() function and is because either the l() or url() functions are being called with a 'query' that is not an array.

Those functions expect the 'query' option to be an array and it is likely that something is passing a string into them.

Do you have any custom code in modules or themes that is calling l() or url()?

I see you have already seen the issue at http://drupal.org/node/1275048

To debug the problem, add this code to the line before the error line:

```
if (!is_array($options['query'])) {
  die(print_r(func_get_args()));
}
```

Then reload the page with the error and you will get a bunch of text on a white screen.
Post that text back here and/or that drupal.org issue.

**After your latest information**
There is a bug in logintoboggan that makes this break whenever you have a redirect url with a query string in it (that is the part with ?key1=value1&key2=value2).

I have made a patch to fix it in the issue mentioned above.

Comment: I just posted the results in the Drupal.org thread, but you gave me two separate code snippets. I used the one in your Drupal post.

Comment: Yeah, I put this one here because it will have much smaller output. Because you can post it in a txt file on drupal but you can't do that here. I will take a look at the drupal.org one later when I have some time.

Comment: Here's what I got when I ran the snippet from your comment above: `Array ( [0] => /~mysite/ [1] => Array ( [query] => q=node/add/photo-gallery-image [fragment] => [absolute] => 1 ) ) 1` . The "node/add/photo-gallery-image" path is the redirect I have set up in LoginToboggan. I believe my error was the fact that I had the entire url in that redirect field, instead of the "node/add/photo-gallery-image" path. Once I changed it to "node/add/photo-gallery-image", my problem was solved. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your info. I found the bug in logintoboggan and submitted a patch to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that you get this error when registering new users so check your form, there you will be missing # in front of a property e.g. type instead of #type or name instead of #name etc. This is the case which I have come across when i get this type of error.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Where exactly would I check for those missing # symbols?

Comment: In this case that is not the problem. You are describing a form API error, whereas this is a url() related error.